# Why iam getting memory segment fault when i'm runing this C program

Tags: c

I have 2 threads and they should use the same memory. Main method should start both threads. Trå A must read the contents of a file and share it with Trå B. Trå B must also receive the data that Trå A has shared and loop through and count the number of bytes in the file. Both Threads run but on the last step before the program terminates before I memory segment fault. I use Semaphore to communicate between the Threads. here i my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096
typedef struct _Buffer
{
    int size;
    char data[BUFFER_SIZE];
} Buffer;

sem_t task1, task2;

void *thread_A(void *arg);
void *thread_B(void *arg);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    Buffer *memory = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));

    sem_init(&task1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&task2, 0, 0);

    pthread_t thread_A_id;
    pthread_t thread_B_id;

    pthread_create(&thread_A_id, NULL, &thread_A,  &memory);

    pthread_create(&thread_B_id, NULL, &thread_B,  &memory);
    
    if (pthread_join(thread_A_id, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error joining thread A");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pthread_join(thread_B_id, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error joining thread B");
        exit(1);
    }

    free(memory);
    return 0;
}

void *thread_A(void *arg)
{
    Buffer *buffer = (Buffer*) arg;

    FILE *pdf_file = fopen("file.pdf", "rb");
    if (pdf_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can not open the file");
    }

    printf("size of struct %ld\n", sizeof(Buffer));
    buffer->size = fread(&buffer->data, sizeof(char), BUFFER_SIZE, pdf_file);

    fclose(pdf_file);

    sem_post(&task1); 
   
    sem_wait(&task2);
    printf("A is out\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *thread_B(void *arg)
{
    printf("IAM IN TREAD B");
    Buffer *buffer = (Buffer*) arg;
    
    sem_wait(&task1);
    int i=0;;

    int byte_counts[256] = {0};
    while (buffer->size != i) {
                    
        unsigned char byte = buffer->data[i];
        byte_counts[byte]++;

        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        printf("Byte-value %02X: %d\n", i, byte_counts[i]);
    }

    sem_post(&task2);

    printf("threadB is done 2\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't even compile. You cannot cast a `void *` to a `Buffer`.

Comment: @Thomas updated it. its compile both and without

Comment: Then you are using a non-standard compiler or you have configured your compiler to accept non-standard C code. Fix that first.

Comment: what is the program output?

Comment: `(buffer->size != i)` Here `buffer` is a struct, not a pointer. Using `->` should not compile.

Comment: @Thomas using normal linux machine, but any way iam getting memory segment fault if use void or not.

Comment: @pmod the program out put is the count of bytes per each character. and its printing B have done and A is Done too. and getting right after all the thing will be printed

Comment: @Gerhardh, its buffer, stack overflow automaticly ignoring some (*) some time. updated the code

Comment: In code sections `*` is normally not ignored.

Comment: it does some time, itried many time now, and I updated the code manuelly

Answer (score 1):

`memory` is a pointer to a `Buffer` (`Buffer *`), and by taking its address, you get a pointer to a pointer to a buffer (`Buffer **`):

```
    Buffer *memory = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
    ...
    pthread_create(&thread_A_id, NULL, &thread_A,  &memory);
    pthread_create(&thread_B_id, NULL, &thread_B,  &memory);
```

But in the thread functions, you're assuming that `arg` is a `Buffer *`:

```
    Buffer *buffer = (Buffer*) arg;
```

This causes undefined behaviour.

Clearly there's one indirection too many; `memory` is already a pointer so we don't need to take its address:

```
    pthread_create(&thread_A_id, NULL, &thread_A,  memory);
    pthread_create(&thread_B_id, NULL, &thread_B,  memory);
```